# No last property for "set" any more?

Tags: swift, set

The book I've read claims that *"You can use the first and last properties, which return one of the elements in the set"*.

However, I've tried it and seems it is not working. I would very appreciate if someone can explain it for me.

[image]

Comment: 1) Post code, not screenshots. – 2) `Set` has not `last` property. Where is that claimed? Which Swift/Xcode version does the book refer to? Which book?

Comment: Please, avoid posting code screenshots. It's much easier to help on real code :)

Comment: A `Set` is an **unordered** collection type by definition, therefore there can't be a distinct *last* object.

Comment: In the book "Swift Apprentice, Beginning programming with Swift 2" Chapter 12, Page 147, The third peragraphy

Comment: Good to Known that. I'll use code more from now on

Comment: @vadian: With that reasoning, there is no distinct *first* object, but there is a `first` property ...

Comment: @MartinR I think that's a *collateral damage* due to the conformance to `CollectionType` / `SequenceType`. The Foundation counterpart has no `first` property.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You cannot ask for the last item of a `Set`. Indeed, a `Set` is not ordered, so there is not `last` item (nor `last` property).

Don't hesitate to take a look at the [Swift Doc on Set](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/CollectionTypes.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014097-CH8-ID105).

If you want to find the last element, you need an ordered collection like an `Array`:

```
var myArray = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
print(myArray.last) // Display 5
```

Comment: Thanks, I'll check more on the official document

Comment: Why then does `Set` have a `first` property? :)

Comment: Indeed, `Set` have a `first` property, but it does not return the first object of the set (because it's not ordered), as the doc says, it's the equivalent of `self.generate().next().`

Comment: A `Set` is a collection of objects with *no defined ordering*. That is slightly different from "unordered" (as I see it). For a concrete set, each element has a unique index, so the elements have an order (there are even `indexOf()`, `startIndex`, `endIndex` for sets).

Comment: Indeed, you're right:  `A set stores distinct values of the same type in a collection with no defined ordering.`

Answer (score 0):

You can revert it back to `Array` which has `last` property. Do it this way:

```
let last = Array(Set([1, 2, 3, 4, 5])).last
```